# How to stop a bean from instantiation after being registered in BeanDefinitionRegistry

Tags: spring, spring-bean

I need to de-register few beans from instantiation after being registered in BeanDefinitionRegistry. I need to do this on some condition.

If i write a code like this

```
@Component
public class DomainConfig implements BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor {

@Override
public void postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(BeanDefinitionRegistry beanDefinitionRegistry) throws BeansException {
    beanDefinitionRegistry.removeBeanDefinition("createBlahExporter");
    beanDefinitionRegistry.removeBeanDefinition("createBlahDataSource");
    beanDefinitionRegistry.removeBeanDefinition("createBlahMonitorSettings");
    beanDefinitionRegistry.removeBeanDefinition(("com.blah.BlahConfiguration));
}
}
```

I get the following error :

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field blahDataExporter in com.blah.BlahConfiguration required a bean of type 
'com.blah.export.Exporter' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

The following candidates were found but could not be injected:
- Bean method 'createProviderDumpExporter' in 'ProviderDumperConfig' not loaded because 
@ConditionalOnProperty (providers.dump.local.enabled=true) found different value in property 
'providers.dump.local.enabled'


Action:

Consider revisiting the entries above or defining a bean of type 'com.harman.inca.export.Exporter' in 
your configuration.
```

Even after removing from here, someone, somewhere is holding the registered names. How do i remove the beans from registered set of beans.

Comment: what is the use case? can't you conditionally load it on start up instead?

Comment: I cant use application.properties. How can i use @ConditionalOnExpression on some environment variables or variables fromConfigFactory

Comment: I want to instantiate a set of beans only when a configurational property is set. This property cannot be set in application.properties. This property can be parsed and set in com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory. Had it been in application.properties, i could have easily used @ConditionalExprssion.

Answer (score 1):

You don’t specify what is ConfigFactory, but consider adding your own implementation of Conditional.

The custom conditional could read the definition from this configuration factory and the annotation bound to this custom conditional predicate could be put on the beans that you’ve planned to “de-register”. With this approach they won’t be registered in the application context so you won’t need to deregister them.

There are many tutorials on how to implement these custom conditions:

Schematically you should:

1. Implement the logic of the condition

```
class OnConfigFactoryCondition implements Condition {

  @Override
    public boolean matches(
        ConditionContext context, 
        AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
      // analyze the value from ConfigFactory whatever it is
      Return true /false
    }
}
```

2. Create a conditional annotation bound to your condition:

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Conditional(OnConfigFactoryCondition.class)
public @interface ConditionalOnConfigFactory {
  ...
}
```

Then you can put this annotation next to `@Component` definition or `@Bean` if you’re using Java Config